# is it possible swift func get <T> enum?

Tags: swift, types, enums, func

there's two func get enum from parameter,
is it possible those func combined just one func?

```swift
func rushdownSetupListener(event: RushdownListenEvent, handler: @escaping ([Any], SocketAckEmitter) -> Void) -> UUID? {
        guard let client = self.client else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let listenerId = client.on(event.rawValue, callback: handler)
        
        return listenerId
    }
    
    func hystoriaSetupListener(event: HystoriaListenEvent,handler: @escaping ([Any], SocketAckEmitter) -> Void) -> UUID? {
        guard let client = client else {
            return nil
        }
        let listenerId = client.on(event.rawValue, callback: handler)
        
        return listenerId
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how `RushdownListenEvent` and `HystoriaListenEvent` are declared?

Comment: @Sweeper it just return String:) like this 
`enum HystoriaListenEvent: String { case STATE = "hystoriaState", case PLAY = "hystoriaPlay" }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both of those enums have a `String` as their raw value, they both conform to `RawRepresentable` where `RawValue == String`. Therefore, you can introduce a generic parameter type constrained to exactly that:

```
func setupListener<EventType>(event: EventType, handler: @escaping ([Any], SocketAckEmitter) -> Void) -> UUID? 
    where EventType: RawRepresentable, EventType.RawValue == String {
    guard let client = self.client else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let listenerId = client.on(event.rawValue, callback: handler)
    
    return listenerId
}
```

You should be able to even simplify the function body to just:

```
client?.on(event.rawValue, callback: handler)
```

Comment: thanks. but my need is func know type but it two enums, in your code I think there's no different between event: String :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you rewrite it into better English? You want to rewrite the two functions into a common function to reduce code duplication, right? That's what the `setupListener` function I showed does. You can replace calls to `rushdownSetupListener` and `hystoriaSetupListener` with `setupListener`.

Comment: @blurple "there's no different between event: String" What do you mean? It has at least one difference - the caller looks like `setupListener(event: HystoriaListenEvent.STATE) { ... }` rather than `setupListener(event: HystoriaListenEvent.STATE.rawValue)`. You can also get the type by inspecting `EventType.self` (but you don't seem to be doing that in the function anyway...)

Comment: The answer @Sweeper has given to you is the one that works for your question. He also went the extra mile suggesting how to make that function body even more concise.

Comment: @Sweeper I think there's other strict for the type, but this was the best way. Thank you so much. :)